# Guides the User with Prompts to go through a procedure and Records User Input

Tags: beginner, vba, excel

I am making a prototype worksheet that follows 9 step problem solving procedure.

Some improvements I'm considering would be to iterate over some of it instead of making a new code line for every single variant.  More or less I need to optimize this code so I can learn how to do this type of thing in the future.

It's not a very straight looping process and I can't think of any good ways to set it up.

Here is a picture of the sheet that the values will go into.

[image]

Here is my code

```
Sub nine_Step()

Dim step1, step2, step3, step4a, step4b, step4c, step4d, step4e, step5a, step5b, step5c, step5d, step5e, step6a, step6b, step6c, step6d, step6e, step7, step8, step9 As Variant


step1 = InputBox("Step 1: Define the Problem.")
    Cells(2, 3).Value = step1


step2 = InputBox("Step 2: What is the Measured Actual Value?")
    Cells(4, 3).Value = step2


step3 = InputBox("Step 3: What is the Target Value Desired?")
    Cells(6, 3).Value = step3

    If step3 <> "" Then
        Cells(7, 3).Value = step3 - step2
    Else:
    End If

step4a = InputBox("Step 4: Why is " & step1 & " happening?")
    Cells(9, 3).Value = step4a
step4b = InputBox("Step 4: Why is " & step4a & " happening?")
    Cells(10, 3).Value = step4b
step4c = InputBox("Step 4: Why is " & step4b & " happening?")
    Cells(11, 3).Value = step4c
step4d = InputBox("Step 4: Why is " & step4c & " happening?")
    Cells(12, 3).Value = step4d
step4e = InputBox("Step 4: Why is " & step4d & " happening?")
    Cells(13, 3).Value = step4e


step5a = InputBox("Step 5: Describe your First Possible Solution")
    Cells(15, 3).Value = step5a
step5b = InputBox("Step 5: Describe your Second Possible Solution")
    Cells(16, 3).Value = step5b
step5c = InputBox("Step 5: Describe your Third Possible Solution")
    Cells(17, 3).Value = step5c
step5d = InputBox("Step 5: Describe your Fourth Possible Solution")
    Cells(18, 3).Value = step5d
step5e = InputBox("Step 5: Describe your Fifth Possible Solution")
    Cells(19, 3).Value = step5e


step6a = InputBox("Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 1")
    Cells(21, 3).Value = step6a
step6b = InputBox("Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 2")
    Cells(22, 3).Value = step6b
step6c = InputBox("Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 3")
    Cells(23, 3).Value = step6c
step6d = InputBox("Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 4")
    Cells(24, 3).Value = step6d
step6e = InputBox("Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 5")
    Cells(25, 3).Value = step6e


step7 = InputBox("Step 7: When did you impliment a solution? Enter a date in 
XX/XX/XXXX format")

If step7 = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Find out when you implimented a solution and enter it when you get a chance.")
Else:
    Cells(28, 3).Value = step7
End If


step8 = InputBox("Step 8: Now that the solution is implemented perminently, what is the current measurement?")
    Cells(31, 3).Value = step8

    If step8 <> "" Then
        Cells(32, 3).Value = Cells(6, 3).Value - step8
    Else:
    End If

step9 = InputBox("Step 9: Any other Ideas that have sprung up since you have started this nine step related to this area?")
    Cells(34, 3).Value = step9

MsgBox ("You have successfully completed this 9 Step.  Congrats!")



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are declaring your variables isn't what you expect it to be. Luckily, you're declaring variants anyway. But if you weren't declaring *Variants* they would all by default be Variants.

```
Dim step1 as variant
Dim step2 as variant, step3 as variant
```

You need to give all variables a type.

You also have some superfluous variables -

> ```
> step6a = InputBox("Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 1")
>     Cells(21, 3).Value = step6a
> step6b = InputBox("Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 2")
>     Cells(22, 3).Value = step6b
> ```

Since you don't re-reference these variables later on, you can just write to the cell

```
.Cells(21,3) = InputBox("Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 1")
.Cells(22,3) = InputBox("Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 2")
```

---

#### Guiding the user

You mention you want to guide the user here. When you prompt them for input, you should tell them what *type* of input, and then check it's the correct Type.

> ```
>  Cells(7, 3).Value = step3 - step2
> ```

This will error if there are values that aren't numerical. You can [define what type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-inputbox-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you want.

You asked me

> What is the Measured Actual Value?

But I didn't know if you wanted what kind of measurement or an integer. This can cause a mismatch error later on.

```
 step3 = Application.InputBox("Step 3: What is the Target Value Desired?", Type:=1)
```

Now you require me to enter a number value. You control what happens if I don't put in the expected type.

---

#### Refactoring

You see yourself doing the same thing over and over. Normally you would farm this out to a function, sending arguments and getting data back. But, you're using the `InputBox` which is already a *function*. So how to make this cleaner? Arrays!

Make yourself an input array and an output array. We know how many questions there are, so no problem.

```
Dim questions(1 to 21) as String
Dim answers(1 to 21) as Variant
```

And then populate your questions and pass them to inputbox with a type, and set each consecutive item in the answers array to the response. Then a simple loop

```
For i = 9 to 25
  .Cells(3,i) = answers(i-8)
Next
```

There are some other things you could do with your strings and whatnot, but that's up to you.

---

#### For the brave

Something like this -

```
Const STEP1 As String = "Define the Problem."
Const STEP2 As String = "What is the Measured Actual Value?"
Const STEP3 As String = "What is the Target Value Desired?"
Const STEP4a As String = "Why is " & questions(1) & " happening?"
Const STEP4b As String = "Why is " & questions(4) & " happening?"
Const STEP4c As String = "Why is " & questions(5) & " happening?"
Const STEP4d As String = "Why is " & questions(6) & " happening?"
Const STEP4e As String = "Why is " & questions(7) & " happening?"
Const STEP5a As String = "Step 5: Describe your First Possible Solution"
Const STEP5b As String = "Step 5: Describe your Second Possible Solution"
Const STEP5c As String = "Step 5: Describe your Third Possible Solution"
Const STEP5d As String = "Step 5: Describe your Fourth Possible Solution"
Const STEP5e As String = "Step 5: Describe your Fifth Possible Solution"
Const STEP6a As String = "Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 1"
Const STEP6b As String = "Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 2"
Const STEP6c As String = "Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 3"
Const STEP6d As String = "Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 4"
Const STEP6e As String = "Step 6: Experiment Measurement Results Solution 5"
Const STEP7 As String = "Step 7: When did you impliment a solution?"
Const STEP8 As String = "Step 8: Now that the solution is implemented perminently, what is the current measurement?"
Const STEP9 As String = "Step 9: Any other Ideas that have sprung up since you have started this nine step related to this area?"

Dim questions(1 To 21) As String
questions(1) = STEP1
questions(2) = STEP2
questions(3) = STEP3
questions(4) = STEP4a
questions(5) = STEP4b
questions(6) = STEP4c
questions(7) = STEP4d
questions(8) = STEP4e
questions(9) = STEP5a
questions(10) = STEP5b
questions(11) = STEP5c
questions(12) = STEP5d
questions(13) = STEP5e
questions(14) = STEP6a
questions(15) = STEP6b
questions(16) = STEP6c
questions(17) = STEP6d
questions(18) = STEP6e
questions(19) = STEP7
questions(20) = STEP8
questions(21) = STEP9
```

Then you can loop through like

```
For i = 1 To 21
    answers(i) = InputBox(questions(i))
End Sub
```

But you might need a custom argument in case you need to restrict what ***Type*** the user can enter. This you cannot do with a UserForm unless you get into keypresses and whatnot.